# Multiple Join tables in classic report; Inserting only first row instead of checked row

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I have question on classic report, which is based on multiple table joins.  On which I have written process to loop and insert only checked box item.  but it only select first item.  However if do this on a single table it work properly.   I would appreciate if someone can help me on inserted selected record when query is based on multiple joins.

My query is as below.

```
select apex_item.checkbox2(1, ord.rowid) sel,
apex_item.text(2,cust.name) Customer,
apex_item.text(3, it.item_id) Item,
apex_item.text(4,it.product_id) Product,
apex_item.text(5,price) price,
apex_item.text(6,quantity)||apex_item.hidden(7,ord.id)   qty
from s_ord ord,
s_item it,
s_customer cust
where ord.id=it.ord_id
and cust.id=ord.customer_id
```

My process is as follow;

```
for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count loop
    APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGE.LOG_MESSAGE(p_message => 'G_F01 : '||APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i), p_level => 1);
    APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGE.LOG_MESSAGE(p_message => '   Q1 : '||APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(i), p_level => 1);
    APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGE.LOG_MESSAGE(p_message => '   P1 : '||APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(i), p_level => 1);
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Or why looping in tabular form with multiple table join, does not work while looping.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't do that if a tabular form is created as a `JOIN` of two (or more) tables (didn't investigate why).

Here's what I do:

- I base my tabular form on one table (the one I'm planning to work (insert, update) with
- columns, that are normally fetched from other tables (using `JOIN`s) are displayed using **functions**

That fixes the issue.

For example: you want to update employee's information, but also display department name they work in.

Don't:

```
select e.empno, 
  e.ename, 
  d.dname,
  e.sal
from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;
```

Do:

```
create function f_dname (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type) 
  return dept.dname%type
is
  retval dept.dname%type;
begin
  select max(d.dname) 
    into retval
    from dept d
    where d.deptno = par_deptno;
  return retval;
end;
/

select e.empno, 
  e.ename, 
  f_dname (e.deptno) dname,  --> function instead of DEPT.DNAME
  e.sal
from emp e;                  --> no join
```

I hope it'll help.